# Retrieving Facebook Live comments in real-time from Webhook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I'm trying to write a program that can retrieve the comments (as they happen) in my Facebook Live videos.  Looking through the Docs I see the following text:

> Reading Comments and Reactions
>
> You can read live video comments by polling the Video Comment edge. In order to do this in the most efficient way so as not to exceed Graph API rate limits, we recommend receiving API updates via webhooks. You can also read live video reactions by polling the Reactions edge.

When I look at `webhooks` I can't seem to find any documentation that states how often they are called.  Are they called on *every* comment, or at some pre-defined interval?

Also, webhooks callbacks run the risk of being received out of order.  What's the best way to ensure that no messages are missed?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever give this a try? What are you subscribing to? I tried live_videos but I only seem to get notified when a stream starts.

Comment: hmm , i think webhook's comments is not working for facebook live videos. We can only polling videos for receiving comments.

Answer (score 2):

As of 3/7/2017 it is possible to be alerted about a comment posting via webhook but the comment itself are not sent in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently they updated their documentation. They dont suggest to use webhooks anymore for live comments. Now they suggest to use Polling. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/production-broadcasts#comments